# Is it safe to access objects with different indexes in NSMutableArray from separate threads?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, thread-safety

I have a NSMutableArray with some objects and I know NSMutableArray is not a thread-safe class. I wonder if it is OK to access each object in that array from a different thread as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < muArr.count; i++) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        muArr[i] = [[NSObject alloc] init];
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippet is not accessing each object in the array (`muArr`), it is *setting* it. The definition of "not thread safe" rules out guaranteed safe write access...

As you are using `dispatch` what you can do is create controlled access to the mutable array, something along the lines of:

- Create a concurrent dispatch queue to use with the array
- Write operations can be dispatched as asynchronous barrier operations to this queue
- Read operations are synchronous operations
- You can wrap it all up in a subclass of `NSMutableArray` if you wish, just follow the subclassing requirements for it given in the documentation.

If you get stuck designing and implementing something like this ask a new question (after checking SO and other sources first) showing your code and explaining your issue and somebody will undoubtedly help you out.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm sorry my expression above is not very clear. That snippet is what I'm trying to do, just setting objects from different threads and no accesses. I want to know if this would cause any problems like crashes.

Comment: @P.Tsin - The statement `muArr[i] = [[NSObject alloc] init];` creates a new object and then assigns a reference to that to an index in your mutable array. You are using multiple async dispatches to a concurrent queue to do this to every existing index in the array. This is exactly what you **cannot** do safely because `NSMutableArray` is not thread safe. HTH